# Income tax calculation using different slabs in php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, tax

I am trying to do a work on TAX CALCULATION using `php`.The required slabs or criterion for the tax calculation is based on `AGE` ,`startincome` and `endincome` . I am using `CODEIGNITER` framework.As I am new to this I have no idea on how to get the things done.

My code should contain only dynamic variables as  the 'slabs' that are to be get from the Database and result should be produced based on the AGE and Salary given at random.

---

My view file is given below:tax.php

```
<form>
   <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="30">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <b>Tax calculation</b>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="name"><b>Name</label>
        </td>
    <td>
       <input id="name" name="name" type="textbox" placeholder="enter your name" size="30" >
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <label for="name"><b>Age</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input id="name" name="name" type="textbox"placeholder="enter your age" size="30" >
        </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
       <td>
          <label for=""><b>Salary:</label></td>
       <td>
          <input id="salary" name="phone" type="textbox"placeholder="enter your yearly salary" size="30" >
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <div>
               <input type="submit" value="calculate" name="submit" />
          </div>
       </td>
       <td>
           <label for=""><strong>Tax Amount:</strong></label>
           <input id="Tax" name="tax" type="textbox" size="17" >
       </td>    
      </table>  
 </form>
```

---

My controller code is below:Tax.php

```
<?php

class Tax extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {   
        $servername='localhost';
        $username='root';
        $password='';
        $database='register';
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password);
        $this->load->view('tax');
        //$this->load->model(Taxmodel);

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        { 
            //echo"inside submit";
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('age','Age','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('salary','Salary','trim|required',array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.'));

           //checks whether the validation returns true or false
            if ($this->form_validation->run() ==TRUE) 
            {
                //echo' validation check';

                 //storing data to Array
                $userdata = array(
                'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'Age' => $this->input->post('age'),
                'Salary' => $this->input->post('salary')
                );
                print_r($userdata);
                $this->load->model('Taxmodel');
                //$this->Taxmodel->insertdata($userdata);
            }

        }
    }
    public function getresult()//to get database values in a row
    {   
    echo "inside getresult";
    $salary=$_POST['salary'];
        $data= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `admin_income` WHERE age<".$age." and age in (SELECT max(age) FROM `admin_income` WHERE age<".$age." order by `age` desc) order by `age` desc ");
        print_r($data);                 
        $result=$conn->query($data);

        Global $totaltax;


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {echo "inside while1";
            while($salary>= $row[$start_incom] && $salary< $row[$end_incom])
                {
                    //echo"Inside tax calculation";
                    $diff=$salary-$startincome;
                    $tax=(($percentage/100)*$diff);
                    echo $tax;
                }
            echo $tax;
        }
    }
    public function extamount()
    {//to get the additional amount to be added
        /*$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM admin_income LIMIT 1;");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $query->next_row('array')*/

                if($initial_income>$start_incom)//codnition for checking whether the salary exceeds first slab
                {
                    $diffresult=$end_incom-$start_incom;
                    $adtntax=[($percentage/100)*$diffresult];
                    echo $adtntax;

                }
                $totaltax=$adtntax+$tax;
        //}
    }
}
```

?>

---

My model name is Taxmodel.php

Database Table
[image: Database table]

I am new to CodeIgniter. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that your `<input>` elements all have unique IDs and that the names are correct on each.

Comment: My question is simple.I want to calculate the tax amount for a particular age and the yearly salary given.actually the code also shows error in the public function **extamount**.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @SajuSJ what is the error? also why are you using brackets around: `$adtntax=[($percentage/100)*$diffresult];` try removing the brackets and replacing with parenthesis (or nothing as its not required for the calc)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code and worked for me you can take it as a reference. Create range array like:

```
<?php
$getTaxCharge = array(
    array(
        'amount_range_from' => 0,
        'amount_range_to' => 250000,
        'tax_percentage' => 0,
         ),
    array(
        'amount_range_from' => 250001,
        'amount_range_to' => 500000,
        'tax_percentage' => 10,
         ),
    array(
        'amount_range_from' => 500001,
        'amount_range_to' => 1000000,
        'tax_percentage' =>20,
         ),
    array(
        'amount_range_from' => 1000001,
        'amount_range_to' => 100000000000,
        'tax_percentage' =>30,
         )
    
);
$calculateTaxOnAmount = 900000;
$remainingAmount      = $calculateTaxOnAmount;
$amount               = $calculateTaxOnAmount;
$arrayAmount          = array();
foreach ($getTaxCharge as $key => $value) {
    $resultArray = array();
    if ($calculateTaxOnAmount > $value['amount_range_to']) {
        $sum                       = $value['amount_range_to'] - $value['amount_range_from'];
        $resultArray['amount']     = $sum;
        $resultArray['percentage'] = $value['tax_percentage'];
        array_push($arrayAmount, $resultArray);
        $remainingAmount = $remainingAmount - $sum;
    } else {
        $resultArray['amount']     = $remainingAmount;
        $resultArray['percentage'] = $value['tax_percentage'];
        array_push($arrayAmount, $resultArray);
        break;
    }
}
$resultantTaxAmount = 0;
foreach ($arrayAmount as $key => $value) {
    $cal                = (($value['amount'] * $value['percentage']) / 100);
    $resultantTaxAmount = $resultantTaxAmount + $cal;
}

echo round($resultantTaxAmount);
?>
```